# What is the easiest way of making a TCP server available from the Internet?

Tags: networking

I have written the Java code for a simple TCP server that is supposed to route data from a master client to a slave client without storing it. The code is working when testing on localhost and it is not a problem here, as I can change it as needed. I can even write it in another language.

I have tried uploading it to AWS, but, for some arcane reason, no instance I create there is available for connection to any computer I have access to, even though I followed the tutorial on their site (it either says 'connection refused' or 'connection timed out' depending on the OS I try connecting from if the instance is linux-based or that the remote desktop is not available if the instance is windows-based).

I am not sure whether I would be able to host it myself because I do not have access to the router settings in order to make port forwarding possible. Also, I tried using tools like ngrok for port tunneling without success.

I am asking what the easiest ways of making a TCP server available to the Internet are, as I need to access it from outside my own network (specifically, from an Android app, through GPRS). If there is a server-less way I can route data from the master to the slave, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: For AWS in particular, you need to ensure you have [security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) configured correctly.

Comment: @user4556274 At one point, I got so desperate I was allowing any kind of access from anywhere. Pretty sure security groups were not the problem

Comment: IS the program unable to make an outgoing connection or an incoming connection?  One requires you to forward the port to the client the other shouldn't require it unless the your network security is configured where it is explicitly required.

Comment: @Ramhound I am unable to ssh into the instance in order to upload my code on AWS. When trying to host it myself, the port tunneling tool cannot establish a connection to the proxy it uses to tunnel traffic.

Comment: Your unable to ssh, so is that because of your local security settings or the settings on the aws instance?

Comment: @Ramhound AWS instance settings. I tried connecting from different machines with different network settings, all unsuccessfully.

Comment: So your going to have to enable root ssh access on your was instance there are hundreds of tutorials online that explain the process.  How you configure a server to allow ssh access is slightly out of scope, unless you tell us what you have done, exactly and provide us the relevant information.  How you make a TCp connection to a server application and how you enable ssh are two entirely different things

Comment: @Ramhound I have followed multiple tutorials step-by-step to no end. Also, I cannot connect to Windows Server instances via remote desktop either.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Comment: @BogdanIonică Ok, So again is that because of your security settings or the server's security settings? Being by unable to connect to a server is that unusual if it's done on purpose

Comment: @Ramhound AWS instance settings again, I presume. I had done the security group settings for the instance and the connection consisted of simply double-clicking a .rdp file. I suppose there is nothing I could have done wrong, unlike ssh.

Comment: typicaly Remote Desktop connections are not enabled by default on Windows Server